# Make Table Column Footer appear only in the last page, in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

My Jasper Report has a table element, and it has a element jr:columnFooter.
I would like that this columnfooter to appear only in the last page, but I don't find any property to do that, or a way to do that.

There is the report propery to ignorePagination, but still It renders the report in one unique page. O course the footer appears in the end, but It has only one page.

So, someone can help me in this quest?

Thanks in advance.